# Shared Preference or Persistent Storage in BlackBerry 10

Tags: sharedpreferences, key-value, blackberry-10, persistent-storage

I want to know if there is an option for storing a KEY-VALUE pair in persistent storage of a mobile device for Blackberry 10.

If yes, How to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cascades provides the [QSettings](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qsettings.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

View the Starship settings example for how to use this. [Starship settings code at github](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/next/starshipsettings)

Answer (score 0):

There is QSettings in class and i have provided the methods for reading and writing QSettings

```
void MainWindow::writeSettings()
 {
     QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");

     settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
     settings.setValue("size", size());
     settings.setValue("pos", pos());
     settings.endGroup();
 }

 void MainWindow::readSettings()
 {
     QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");

     settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
     resize(settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400)).toSize());
     move(settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint());
     settings.endGroup();
 }
```